# What is the correct way to handle "IllegalStateException: database already closed" , while creating the database in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

There are many one - liner solutions that might correct the error , but can any one give an complete description or an example on what should be  right way to open , do some operation( delete/query etc.) on the database ,close cursor and close database while doing this all from a separate functions , that could be called from any thread.

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces your problem.